# CarouselView does not scroll to the correct page in MAUI app

Tags: c#, .net, maui

When I try to add a new view model to the ovservable collection binding with carousel view item source in query apply function like this:

```cs
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
{
    if (query.ContainsKey("add_city_name"))
    {
        string cityName = query["add_city_name"].ToString();
                
        var weather = allWeathers.Where(w => w.name == cityName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (weather == null)
        {
            new WeatherViewModel(cityName).setOnWeatherLoadedCallback
            (
                vm => { 
                    allWeathers.Insert(0, vm);
                    currentItem = vm;  //Doesnt work
                    scrollCallback(vm);
                    showAlert($"City {cityName} is added.");
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(canSwipe));
                    saveCityData();
                }                           
            );
        }
        else
        {
            currentItem = weather;
            //scrollCallback(weather);
            showAlert($"City {cityName} aready exists.");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is onLoadedCallback:

```cs
public partial class WeatherViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    WeatherData _weatherData = null;
    Action<WeatherViewModel> onWeatherLoaded = null;
    Action<WeatherViewModel> onWeatherLoading = null;

    public WeatherData weatherData
    {
        get
        {
            return _weatherData;
        }
        set
        {
            _weatherData = value;
            onWeatherLoaded?.Invoke(this);
            OnPropertyChangedAll();
        }
    }
}
```

And after load the weather data from internet, change the currentItem value, it is binding with carousel view current item,

```xml
<CarouselView
    x:Name="carousel_view"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0, 1, 1"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
    CurrentItem="{Binding currentItem}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding allWeathers}"
    IndicatorView="indicator_view"
    IsSwipeEnabled="{Binding canSwipe}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MyViews:WeatherPage
                Margin="20, 70, 20, 0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

I dont know why the carousel view does not scroll to the specified page, and the currentItem value in the view model class is different from carousel view cuurentItem, I dont know why, isn't it data binding? How could they be different?
And then I added a callBack when add a new view model try to scroll to the page manually

```cs
mainPageWeathersViewModel = new MainPageWeathersViewModel()
{
    scrollCallback = vm => carousel_view.ScrollTo(vm)          
};
this.BindingContext = mainPageWeathersViewModel;
```

But it still doesn't work sometimes

Like this demo, run on android device:

Main page view model:

```cs
partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
    {

        PageViewModel _currentItem;
        public CarouselView carouselView;
        public PageViewModel currentItem 
        {   get 
            {
                return _currentItem;
            } 
            set
            {
                if (_currentItem != value) { _currentItem = value; } 
            } 
        }

        public ObservableCollection<PageViewModel> pages { get; private set; }


        public MainViewModel() 
        {
            pages = new ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>();
        }
        public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
        {
            if (query.ContainsKey("add_new_page"))
            {
                string pageName = query["add_new_page"].ToString();

                var page = pages.Where(p => p.name == pageName).FirstOrDefault();

                if (page != null) 
                {
                    currentItem = page;
                }
                else
                {
                    var newPage = new PageViewModel { name = pageName };
                    pages.Insert(0, newPage);
                    currentItem = newPage; //It doesn't work, in this view model class currentItem will change but not in view 
                }
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void showCurrentItemInfo()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            ToastDuration duration = ToastDuration.Long;
            double fontSize = 14;

            var text = $"Current item in view model is {currentItem.name}, in view is {((PageViewModel)carouselView.CurrentItem).name}.";

            var toast = Toast.Make(text, duration, fontSize);

            await toast.Show(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
```

And this is main page:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel { carouselView = carousel_view };
    }

    private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NewPage1));
    }
}
```

Main page xmal:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:myApp ="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             >

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="20"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <CarouselView                
                x:Name="carousel_view"
                HeightRequest="300"
                WidthRequest="300"
                CurrentItem="{Binding currentItem}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding pages}"
                IndicatorView="indicator_view">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <VerticalStackLayout
                            BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding name}"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>

            <IndicatorView 
                x:Name="indicator_view"
                IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="Gray"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="New  page"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                Command="{Binding showCurrentItemInfoCommand}"
                Text="SHOW CURRENT"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Another page just to input page name to get a new page, duplicate page will not be created:

```cs
public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..?add_new_page={entry.Text}");
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Entry 
            x:Name="entry"
            Margin="0, 50, 0, 0"
            WidthRequest="200"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
            Margin="0, 50, 0, 0"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"
            Text="ADD PAGE"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In main page, after adding a new page, carousel view won't scroll to the new page, there is a button to show current item, and I tried, the current item in view model class is different than in view.

Comment: Are `allWeathers`, `currentItem` and `canSwipe` members or properties?

Comment: All are Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

You can try to add attribute `ObservableProperty` for `currentItem`,just as follows:

```
  [ObservableProperty]
  private PageViewModel currentItem;
```

then your app will generate variable `CurrentItem` automatically.
And then use this variable `CurrentItem` around your app.

```
          if (page != null)
            {
                //currentItem = page;
                CurrentItem = page;
            }
            else
            {
                var newPage = new PageViewModel { name = pageName };
                pages.Insert(0, newPage);
                // currentItem = newPage; //It doesn't work, in this view model class currentItem will change but not in view 
                CurrentItem = newPage;
            }
```

Besides, remember to bind `CurrentItem` to your CarouselView:

```
           <CarouselView                
            x:Name="carousel_view"
            HeightRequest="300"
            WidthRequest="300"
            CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding pages}"
            IndicatorView="indicator_view">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VerticalStackLayout
                        BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding name}"
                            TextColor="Black"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

You can refer to the full code as follows:

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable 
{

    public CarouselView carouselView;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private PageViewModel currentItem;

    //PageViewModel _currentItem;
    //public PageViewModel currentItem
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return _currentItem;
    //    }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        if (_currentItem != value) 
    //        {
    //            _currentItem = value;

    //          //  OnPropertyChanged("currentItem");
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

    public ObservableCollection<PageViewModel> pages { get; private set; }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        pages = new ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>();
    }
    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        if (query.ContainsKey("add_new_page"))
        {
            string pageName = query["add_new_page"].ToString();

            var page = pages.Where(p => p.name == pageName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (page != null)
            {
                //currentItem = page;
                CurrentItem = page;
            }
            else
            {
                var newPage = new PageViewModel { name = pageName };
                pages.Insert(0, newPage);
                // currentItem = newPage; //It doesn't work, in this view model class currentItem will change but not in view 
                CurrentItem = newPage;
            }
        }
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    public async void showCurrentItemInfo()
    {

        //CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        //ToastDuration duration = ToastDuration.Long;
        //double fontSize = 14;

        //var text = $"Current item in view model is {currentItem.name}, in view is {((PageViewModel)carouselView.CurrentItem).name}.";

        //var toast = Toast.Make(text, duration, fontSize);

        //await toast.Show(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="20"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <CarouselView                
                x:Name="carousel_view"
                HeightRequest="300"
                WidthRequest="300"
                CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding pages}"
                IndicatorView="indicator_view">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <VerticalStackLayout
                            BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding name}"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>

            <IndicatorView 
                x:Name="indicator_view"
                IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="Gray"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="New  page"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                IsVisible="false"
                Command="{Binding showCurrentItemInfoCommand}"
                Text="SHOW CURRENT"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I think it is about the query apply function, from page to another page, then change current item, there will be something wrong.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your viewmodel or a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: I edited, there is a little demo.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check it. It works properly on my side.